# Booting from usb?

Tags: 14.04, live-usb, bios

I have Ubuntu 14.04 running on my laptop right now, but its kind of glitchy so I want to switch to Zorin, at least until 14.10 comes out. I made a bootable USB with Startup Disk Creator, but what do I do from here?
My laptop doesn't have a key to open the BIOS settings or whatever when Ubuntu is starting up, is there a way to set the computer to either boot from a usb or open the BIOS before restarting?

Like an option in settings or something? I can't find one, and no search is helping, pleeease help me, I'm not amazing with computers.

*EDIT*: I have the Asus X200CA, if it helps.

Comment: Have you tried searching online for specific instruction about entering the BIOS with your specific laptop (with model number)? Check [this](http://www.pcworld.com/article/241032/how_to_enter_your_pcs_bios.html) for info about the general procedure.

Comment: Why don't you add the make and model of your laptop to your question?  Perhaps someone has the same computer and can suggest what key-combination would allow you to access the BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

The motherboard itself loads up the BIOS. From there it goes to the DVD/HDD/USB

BIOS > Drive > OS

The BIOS will make its "choice" before getting to the disks. If you can't Google your make/model for exact instructions try disconnecting spamming each F key.

Newer BIOS have fastboot which can skip over things quickly, but spam that key one of them WILL work.